# Ninject with MVC4 conditional binding on HttpContext.Current

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm not very experienced with Ninject, so I may have a concept completely wrong here, but this is what I want to do.  I have a multi-tenant web application and would like to inject a different class object depending on what URL was used to come to my site.

Something along the lines of this, although maybe I can use .When() in the binding, but you get the idea:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var currentTenant = TenantLookup.LookupByDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower());
        if (currentTenant.Foldername == "insideeu")
        { kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<AXCustomerRepository>(); }
        else
        { kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>(); }
...
```

The problem is that HttpContext.Current is null at this point.  So my question is how can I get the HttpContext data in NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices.  Any direction on where I might be going wrong with Ninject would be much appreciated as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your binding here resolves at compile time; whereas you need it to resolve at runtime, for every request.  To do this, use `ToMethod`:

```
Bind<ICustomerRepository>().ToMethod(context => 
    TenantLookup.LookupByDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower()).Foldername == "insideeu" 
    ? new AXCustomerRepository() : new CustomerRepository());
```

This means that, every time the `ICustomerRepository` is called for, NInject will run the method using the current `HttpContext`, and instantiate the appropriate implementation.

Note that you can also use `Get` to resolve to the type rather than to the specific constructor:

```
Bind<ICustomerRepository>().ToMethod(context => 
    TenantLookup.LookupByDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower())
        .Foldername == "insideeu" ?  
            context.Kernel.Get<AXCustomerRepository>() : context.Kernel.Get<CustomerRepository>()
    as ICustomerRepository);
```

Comment: That worked great, and thanks for the explanation. I did have to cast the Get calls to the classes' interface (ICustomerRepository) or I would get a "no implicit conversion" error

Comment: @Crob sweet, glad it helped.  I edited in the cast for posterity.

Comment: Hi, I wish to do something similar. I am using the same repository & unit of work but the dbcontext is created per tenant passing in a different connection string for each tenant. This connection string comes from a separate authentication DB. SO my question is, should i do all that login in the ninject registerservices() ?

Comment: I had a totally different Ninject related problem but your answer made me actually figure out compile time vs runtime binding.